# KeyError: 'data' error while parsing Subreddit JSON

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am trying to read title of latest posts from r/chrome subreddit using Python.

But when I execute the python file, I get the `KeyError: 'data' error`

Here's my code:

```
import json, requests

def getReddit():
        redditLatest = requests.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/new/.json').json()
        print(redditLatest['data']['children'][0]['data']['title'])
getReddit()
```

Terminal:

[image: My Terminal]

Please help with a solution.

Comment: It means that the key "data" is not in the resulting dicts. In your case this can happen in two places.

Comment: @MikhailBeliansky If you take a look at JSON i am getting in browser have the data. Check here: https://pastebin.com/VGp6x8uS

Comment: Do `print(redditLatest)`, you'll be surprised

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Mikhail Beliansky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9268478/mikhail-beliansky) already mentioned, debug your response.

```
import requests
redditLatest = requests.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/new/.json').json()
print(redditLatest)
# {'message': 'Too Many Requests', 'error': 429}
```

You can see that reddit recognizes that you are not a "normal" client/browser. Especially because [requests adds a user-agent](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/f6d43b03fbb9a1e75ed63a9aa15738a8fce99b50/requests/utils.py#L822) like "python-requests/2.25.1".

You can add a common browser user-agent to your request. If you don't make too many requests, this may work for you.

```
redditLatest = requests.get(
    'https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/new/.json', 
    headers={'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36'}
).json()
print(redditLatest)
# {'kind': 'Listing', 'data': {...}}
```